# Linkedin Messaging API access

Tags: linkedin-api

How can we gain access to Linkedin Messaging API? Are there any requests to be submitted to Linkedin for this API? Can any one please let  us any contact forms which we can used to submit the request to Linkedin

Comment: I guess this question is out of SO scope. Check this resource first - https://www.linkedin.com/developers/

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a technical question about programming

Comment: I have same question - there is nothing about procedure how to register for messaging API